# getting concurrent modification exception just for trying to read an element of an ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, concurrency

I know i will get this exception when i try to modify or remove from the list, but just for reading from it ?! What is the solution here ?

```
public boolean recieveHello(Neighbor N, HelloMsg H) {
        Iterator<Neighbor> I = NTable.iterator();
        Iterator<Neighbor> J = NTable.iterator();
        if(!J.hasNext()) {
            this.NTable.add(N);
        }

        while(I.hasNext()) {
            if(I.next().nid == N.getnid()) {  /*EXCEPTION IS HERE*/
                //case where the node is already present in the NTable
            }
            else {
                N.setnhrc(0);  
                this.NTable.add(N);
                //case where the node is to be added to the NTable
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

By the way, I must mention that NTable is an arrayList and is a member of the class whose method this is

### EDIT

I solved the problem using ::

```
public boolean recieveHello(Neighbor N, HelloMsg H) {
        Iterator<Neighbor> I = NTable.iterator();
        Iterator<Neighbor> J = NTable.iterator();
        if(!J.hasNext()) {
            this.NTable.add(N);
        }
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i=0; i<NTable.size(); i++) {
            if(NTable.get(i).nid == N.getnid()) {
                //case where the node is already present in the NTable
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
                N.setnhrc(0);  
                this.NTable.add(N);
                //case where the node is to be added to the NTable
            }
        }
        if(flag == true) {

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what is the actual exception?

Comment: at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:782)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:754)
 at centralAodvnode.CAodvNode.recieveHello(CAodvNode.java:49)
 at transmissionAodvNode.TAodvNode.sendHello(TAodvNode.java:19)
 at unitTest.UnitTest.main(UnitTest.java:26)

Comment: What does the getnid method do?

Comment: it accesses a data of the Neighbor object `N` that is passed to the function.

Comment: the reason your new method works is because in a for loop, the conditional is checked each time. In your case, NTable.size() is called on each loop, and hence the value of i < size is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you're changing the size of the list while iterating over it when you say

```
  this.NTable.add(N);
```

So, instead keep track of which ones to add in a separate list, then append the items after the first iteration.

Comment: but sir, the problem is not at that line at all! its at the line where I am calling I.next().

Comment: @return 0  It doesn't notice the problem until it actually iterates it.